# Slideshow showing 3 images (like Carousel) with some specified details

Tags: jquery, slideshow, center, carousel, caption

I need to make a slideshow which will show three images and slide them exactly like the one in [this website](http://www.frameweb.com/).

The only difference is that I need the first and the third slide to be transparent, so only the middle (active) one will be fully visible and change the design of the caption.

Anyways, I tried the 'Cycle2' plugin which has some features but I couldn't use it like I wanted (to be always centered and cutting out the sides of other slides).

Answer (score 1):

MovingBoxes plugin may help you.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var slideShowDelay = 4000, // 4000 millisecond = 4 seconds
            timer,
            mb = $('#slider').data('movingBoxes'),
            loop = function() {
        // if wrap is true, check for last slide, then stop slideshow
        if (mb.options.wrap !== true && mb.curPanel >= mb.totalPanels) {
            // click the button to pause
            $('button.slideshow').trigger('click');
            return;
        }
        // next slide, use mb.goBack(); to reverse direction
        mb.goForward();
        // run loop again
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            loop();
        }, slideShowDelay);
    };
    // toggle slideshow button
    $('button.slideshow')
            .attr('data-mode', "false") // slideshow paused
            .click(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        // slide show mode
        var mode = $(this).attr('data-mode') === "false",
                // button text, replace with <img> if desired
                button = mode ? "Pause" : "Play";
        if (mode) {
            loop();
        }
        $(this).attr('data-mode', mode).html(button);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jMXx3/3030/)